# how to use regex for detecting correct pattern of email address in android

Tags: android, regex

I am making a user login application in android.In register section for using correct pattern of email address i am  using regex expression.It is working fine but main problem is that i can login as xyz@123.com but i want only (gmail,hotmail,yahoo & rediffmail) not 123 or abc etc.How can i do this.My code is

```
  public static boolean isEmailValid(String email,EditText et) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
        CharSequence inputStr = email;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }else{
            et.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000'>Plese type valid Email Address</font>"));
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

plz help me.

Comment: You need to mark as resolved the answers that solved your problem..

Comment: @MehdiB. ur sol doesnot solve my problem giving (Lang cannot be resolved) error.

Answer (score 3):

Use predefined `EMAIL_ADDRESS` pattern in in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html.

Comment: I think this is a really good idea.  Perhaps use the predefined pattern to confirm "this is a valid email address" and then do additional tests to enforce the business rule "the email address is in gmail.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com, rediff.com, etc".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to let the validation decoupled from any logic (error display, views etc...) :

Create an interface : ValidationCallback.java

```
public interface ValidationCallback {
    void onEval (boolean isValid);
}
```

Then a Utility class where all your validation rules will go (isNumeric is....) : Lang.java

```
public class Lang {

    private final static Set<String> Providers;
    static {
        Providers = new HashSet<String> ();
        Providers.add ("gmail");
        Providers.add ("yahoo");
        Providers.add ("outlook");
    }

    public static void checkEmailValidity (String input, ValidationCallback callback) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onEval (isEmailValid (input));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEmailValid (String input) {
        String emailExp = "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{0,255}\\@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25})+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (emailExp);
        boolean isValid = pattern.matcher (input).matches ();

        if (isValid) {
            String provider = input.split ("@")[1].split (".")[0].toLowerCase ();
            if (!Providers.contains (provider)) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Then from your Activity or another Utility class that has the view :

```
ValidationCallback callback = new ValidationCallback () {

    @Override
    public void onEval (boolean isValid) {
        if (!isValid) {
            editText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000'>Plese type valid Email Address</font>"));
        }
    }
}
Lang.checkEmailValidity (editText.getText (), callback);
```

Or if you don't want to use the callback mechanism :

```
if (!Lang.isEmailValid (editText.getText ())) {
    editText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000'>Plese type valid Email Address</font>"));
}
```

You get the picture, you can tweak it however you want.

Comment: sir it is showing the below one that Lang (cannot resolved).Plz tell me how to remove this problem

Comment: @NickyManali : You need to create it... Create a class `Lang.java` with the above code and create an interface `ValidationCallback.java`..